Why is 을 거예요 conjugated as 겁니다 in formal polite style?
The Wiktionary page for -을 것이다 tells me to use the conjugations for 이다, which would suggest -을 것입니다 or -을 거입니다. The former seems to be correct, but I'm confused about the latter. In my textbook (Integrated Korean Beginning: Beginning 2 (KLEAR Textbooks in Korean Language)) it consistently uses the form -을 겁니다 with no explanation (and in any case the book assumes we only know -을 거이다 and not -을 것이다).
Is -을 거입니다 incorrect? When can I predict that the 이 in 입니다 will be dropped?

The "most" standard would be -ㄹ/을 것입니다, and its colloquial variant -ㄹ/을 겁니다, if we want to remain at the 합쇼체 (formal polite/deferential) level.
